# How can I set up my Windows 7 to use Keyboard layout#JCUKEN (Latin)

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

This is a programming question if there is a way to do so from code in a website... I visited a website and while I was on their page, my keyboard acted so that when I depressed a key, the Cryllic letter of the keyboard layout defined above, appeared in the textarea on their website, so I know it is possible in at least that context.

for instance: [This WebSite does the trick](http://gate2home.com/Russian-Keyboard)

But how to set up my machine to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Control Panel -> Clock, Language, and Region -> Change keyboards or other input methods -> Change keyboards... -> General Tab -> Add... -> Select the type of keyboard you wish to use.

If it is not in there, then you are probably out of luck. I looked it up and found out that it is Russian. I checked the Russian tab in the Windows Keyboard list and it didn't seem to be there. Check still, because I do not know everything about it and maybe it is just under a different name.

Comment: Thanks for your interest but that was a dead end I checked out First.